# UITableView does not render cell while scrolling up quickly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I quickly scroll up in my tableview some of its cells start not being displayed.
As you can see from the picture below my tableview does not display some of its cells.

[image]

I checked my cellforrowatindexpath and it seems to be normally called for all the uitableviewcells. Do you have any idea of where to start debugging be the issue?

Here it is my storyboard configuration:

[image]

Here it is a little portion of code that I wrote to debug the issue, however only the first NSLog gets printed and it all seems to be okay:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CoreDataTVCell *cell = (CoreDataTVCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Cell row: %ld section: %ld", (long)indexPath.row, (long)indexPath.section);

@try {
    cell.managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell updateCell];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Object not found: %@", exception.callStackSymbols);
}

if(!cell)
{
    NSLog(@"Cell not found");
}

return cell;
}
```

The same problem happens also with a simplier TVC with 2 cell identifiers (one for the header and one for the other rows):

[image]

Here it is what i get by printing the visible cells (excluding the first one):

[image]

```
2015-11-19 17:34:28.430 XXX[7483:3224955] ADA APENNINE - <CustomerTVCell: 0x15601e000; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 240; 768 120); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1557bdf50>>
2015-11-19 17:34:28.431 XXX[7483:3224955] ADA APENNINE - <CustomerTVCell: 0x15601e000; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 240; 768 120); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1557bdf50>>
2015-11-19 17:34:28.431 XXX[7483:3224955] AMED - <CustomerTVCell: 0x156036a00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 480; 768 120); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1557b68e0>>
2015-11-19 17:34:28.432 XXX[7483:3224955] AMED - <CustomerTVCell: 0x156036a00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 480; 768 120); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1557b68e0>>
2015-11-19 17:34:28.432 XXX[7483:3224955] AMPARO - <CustomerTVCell: 0x1560dc400; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 720; 768 120); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1556e7980>>
2015-11-19 17:34:28.433 XXX[7483:3224955] AMPARO - <CustomerTVCell: 0x1560dc400; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 720; 768 120); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1556e7980>>
2015-11-19 17:34:28.433 XXX[7483:3224955] ADA APENNINE - <CustomerTVCell: 0x15601e000; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 240; 768 120); clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1557bdf50>>
```

There are 7 rows visible in this case, however it seems that some of them are repeated and others are not there.

Here it is what should be displayed:

```
2015-11-19 17:45:50.314 X[7483:3224955] Cell row: 0 section: 0
2015-11-19 17:45:50.318 X[7483:3224955] Customer: A LA MODE

2015-11-19 17:45:50.321 X[7483:3224955] Cell row: 1 section: 0
2015-11-19 17:45:50.322 X[7483:3224955] Customer: ADA APENNINE

2015-11-19 17:45:50.325 X[7483:3224955] Cell row: 2 section: 0
2015-11-19 17:45:50.326 X[7483:3224955] Customer: ALTON

2015-11-19 17:45:50.329 X[7483:3224955] Cell row: 3 section: 0
2015-11-19 17:45:50.330 X[7483:3224955] Customer: AMED

2015-11-19 17:45:50.337 X[7483:3224955] Cell row: 4 section: 0
2015-11-19 17:45:50.338 X[7483:3224955] Customer: AMIRA

2015-11-19 17:45:50.360 X[7483:3224955] Cell row: 5 section: 0
2015-11-19 17:45:50.361 X[7483:3224955] Customer: AMPARO

2015-11-19 17:45:50.370 X[7483:3224955] Cell row: 6 section: 0
2015-11-19 17:45:50.371 X[7483:3224955] Customer: AMPARO
```

Comment: It looks like your cells are already reused although they should still be visible.

 Are you using different cells with different cellIdentifiers in your table view?

Comment: Yes, there is a segmentedcontrol on the first rows that changes the cellidentifier (and the fetchresultcontroller) and calls the tableview reloaddata method... but the problem happens also if i don't change the segmentedcontrol selection...

Comment: You could try to print out the visible cells, their index paths and their coordinates to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: There is something strange, it seems that in the visible cells some of them are repeated and some of them are missing... I have edited the question with more info, any idea?

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You say you use different cells with different identifiers but you always get the cell with the idetntifier self.cellIndentifier. So how can this varialbe always hold the right value for the different cell types?

Comment: It's a little bit complicated: there is a CoreDataTableViewController superclass, the method I have posted is from the superclass. The actual viewcontreller class calls the superclass methods if the row is > 1, so that the header cell with the segmented control works as expected.

Comment: Well, from your printout of the cells it's clear that your data model is somehow mixed up - some cells are hidden = yes, which means the table thinks they are not visible, and the frames are not right, they should be connected in y value without gaps, and apparently there are always 120 pixels missing in between. It somehow seems you have a problem with the cell heights - did you implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath with the right values? Or are you mixing up the cellForRowAtIndexPath in your child and parent controller?

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: This is not a solution, it's just a workaround!

Reloading data while the user is quickly scrolling up helps.

Properties:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint lastOffset;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastOffsetCapture;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isScrollingFast;
```

Methods:

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    NSTimeInterval timeDiff = currentTime - self.lastOffsetCapture;
    if(timeDiff > 0.1) {
        CGFloat distance = currentOffset.y - self.lastOffset.y;

        CGFloat scrollSpeedNotAbs = (distance * 10) / 1000; //in pixels per millisecond

        //quickly scroll up
        if (scrollSpeedNotAbs < - 3.5) {
            self.isScrollingFast = YES;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
            NSLog(@"Fast!");
        }

        self.lastOffset = currentOffset;
        self.lastOffsetCapture = currentTime;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate) {
        [self scrollingFinish];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self scrollingFinish];
}

- (void)scrollingFinish {
    //enter code here
    if(self.isScrollingFast){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
        self.isScrollingFast = NO;
    }
}
```

Remember to declare the < UIScrollViewDelegate > in your TVC.